# how to query for a time which is less than current time?

Tags: mysql

```
Select CLID, 
from tblname 
where callStartTime < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 minute;
```

This is my query. I want only those clids who come within the last 30 minutes, but on running this query I am getting complete records

Comment: > than I suspect, voting to close as typo

Comment: Change `where callStartTime < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 minute; ` to `where callStartTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 minute; `

Answer (score 2):

To make it easier to solve a problem you should break it on smaller pieces.

You could run :

```
mysql> select NOW() - INTERVAL 30 minute;
+----------------------------+
| NOW() - INTERVAL 30 minute |
+----------------------------+
| 2021-12-21 11:28:02        |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And see the date produced by the condition.

So you are asking `MySQL` to retrieve all the data  before `2021-12-21 11:28:02` ..... `where callStartTime <='2021-12-21 11:28:02'`.

Change it to `where callStartTime >='2021-12-21 11:28:02'`.

So

```
Select CLID, 
from tblname 
where callStartTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 minute;
```